# WPF: Get Target Object from derived Binding Class

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I have derived a Class called "ConfExtension" from Binding. In a nutshell it looks like this:

```
Public Class ConfExtension
    Inherits Binding

    Public Sub New(path As String)
        MyBase.New(path)
        ...
    End Sub

    ...

    Public Property DefaultValue As Object
End Class
```

In XAML I use this Class as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    ...
    Height="{local:Conf Height,DefaultValue=480}"/>
```

How can I access the Target Object of the Binding (In this case the Window) from a Method within my Class?

**EDIT: From my research this seems to be somewhat between tricky and impossible. So here's what I ultimately want to achieve:**

The ConfExtension is supposed to be an easy way to store and retrieve Settings for WPF controls. The Binding path is the storage key and it works fine so far:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    ...
    Height="{imCC:Conf Height,DefaultValue=480}"
    Width="{imCC:Conf Width,DefaultValue=640}"
    Left="{imCC:Conf Left, DefaultValue=0}"
    Top="{imCC:Conf Top, DefaultValue=0}"
    WindowState="{imCC:Conf WindowState,DefaultValue=Normal}"
           >
    ...
</Window>
```

This let's me store and retrieve the Window configuration by saving all values as Strings. But further down the visual tree I might want to reuse the same keys (actually I won't even know what keys have been used) for some other configuration-property-bindings. That's why I came up with the Idea to make some attached properties on the target element that will help me identify (and ultimately group together) the settings for the corresponding element.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    ...

    imCC:Conf.ID="A6236826-9B21-4EFB-BFA4-66C1661E22D7"
    imCC:Conf.Section="Fenstereinstellungen"

    Height="{imCC:Conf Height,DefaultValue=480}"
    Width="{imCC:Conf Width,DefaultValue=640}"
    Left="{imCC:Conf Left, DefaultValue=0}"
    Top="{imCC:Conf Top, DefaultValue=0}"
    WindowState="{imCC:Conf WindowState,DefaultValue=Normal}"
           >
    ...
</Window>
```

(the Class with the Attached Properties is called Conf while the Class that works the Binding is called ConfExtension, both in the Namespace "imCC" thus the same notation in the Markup "imCC:Conf")

My idea was to travel upwards in the Visual Tree from the element that get's my "configuration" binding, grab the next "Conf.ID" and use it as a prefix (or in a similar manner) to identify the corresponding settings.

If it should be the case that I cannot get the **Target** by this method alone, are there other way to achieve this? I've stumbled upon BindingGroupName - is this a breadcrumb to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, in short, is not to inherit from Binding, but from MarkupExtension and cast the serviceProvider to IProvideValueTarget.

I have wrapped my previous code in another ExtensionClass and this achieves what I wanted in my original question (first and foremost get access to the TargetObject)

```
Public Class Conf2Extension
    Inherits Markup.MarkupExtension

    Private _MyName As String
    Public Sub New(MyName As String)
        MyBase.New
        _MyName = MyName
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ProvideValue(serviceProvider As IServiceProvider) As Object
        Dim x As IProvideValueTarget = CType(serviceProvider, IProvideValueTarget)
        Dim TargetObject As DependencyObject = CType(x.TargetObject, DependencyObject)
        Dim TargetProperty As DependencyProperty = CType(x.TargetProperty, DependencyProperty)

        Dim MyConfBinding As New ConfExtension(_MyName) With {.DefaultValue = "This Works!"}
        Return MyConfBinding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider)
    End Function
End Class
```