# How can I get the Target Object and Target Property from a Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, markup-extensions

I will note that this is similar to but different than
[WPF: Get Target Object from derived Binding Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556135/wpf-get-target-object-from-derived-binding-class)
because I'd like to get this information from the basic `Binding` class.

My goal is to get the `Target Object` and `Target Property` of `Binding` given that `Binding` (if it was set).

I have tried to derive a class from `Binding` but unfortunately the method I seem to need to override, `ProvideValue`, is marked as sealed otherwise it would be as simple as:

```cs
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) is IProvideValueTarget target)
    {
        _targetObject = target.TargetObject;
        _targetProperty = target.TargetProperty;
    }
    return base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
}
```

And this would probably only work for `Bindings` set in XAML. Likewise, the solution for the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556135/wpf-get-target-object-from-derived-binding-class) probably also only works in XAML.

I have tried (probably unwisely) to derive from `Binding` and [force override](https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2017/02/11/how-to-override-sealed-function-in-c/) `ProvideValue` because I mostly only set `Bindings` from XAML anyway but I couldn't get it to work anyway.

I need the targets because I'm creating an attachable validation for the `Bindings` because the default Validation has many shortcomings but because `Binding` does not derive from `DependencyObject` I cant attach `DependencyProperty` so I can't get the targets via the standard avenue.

Comment: The Binding only contains information about the data source. Why don't you attach your behavior to the binding target? What shortcomming are you referring to? You can use Binding validation or property validation by implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo. Both allow you to validate the binding data and to provide a GUI feedback. What are you missing? You are very likely on the wrong path.

Comment: The standard `ValidationRule` doesn't derive from `DependencyObject` which limits the potential. I figured the best place to attach it would be the `Binding` because that is what I am validating.

Comment: What potential? You get the value of the binding and return whether it is valid or not. You don't need any DependencyObject features in order to validate the data value of the binding. You are probably not understanding binding and property validation and/or you are doing something wrong. I'm still wondering what exact feature you are missing?

Comment: The fact that you need to know the binding target in order to validate the data is a good indicator that you are misunderstanding the concept.

Comment: For example If I want textBox1 to be valid only if it does not contain some string that is the text in a different textBox2. I can't bind the textBox2.Text to a ValidationRule.

Comment: I need to know the target because I need to call `BindingExpression.ValidateWithoutUpdate` and to get the `BindingExpression` I call `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression` which requires the target information